# Junk character automatically changing after committing code into SVN repository

Tags: java, svn, svn-repository

I am facing below issue in removing junk character using Java. I am using below code to remove junk character

```
colData = colData.replace(-Â­,"- ");
```

It's working fine locally before committing the code into SVN repository. But when we commit same line of code, its not working. Because its changing above code to below line of code:

```
colData = colData.replace(-Ã,Â­,"- ");
```

Can anyone suggest me why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the filesystem. It's better not to use this inside code anyway. Use new (char) 199 , which I believe is the ASCII code for that character, instead.